# Where is $f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\langle nx\rangle}{n^2+n}$ discontinuous?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $\langle x\rangle$ denote the fractional part of $x\in
>  \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\langle x\rangle := \inf \{ x-k: k\in \mathbb{Z},
>  k\leq x \}$.
>
> 1. Define $$f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\langle 
>         nx\rangle}{n^2+n}.$$ What is the domain of $f$?
> 2. Is $f$ Riemann integrable on any bounded interval? If so, evaluate
>      $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.
> 3. Find all points where $f$ is discontinuous.

I'm fine with #1 and #2...I think the answer to #3 should be $\mathbb{Q}$, but [this](http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Advanced_Calculus%3a_2010_January%3a_Problem_4) answer suggests that the function is continuous at the integers. I don't see any reason why it would be. What do you think?

Comment: I think you are correct and the web page is mistaken.

Comment: Agreed. And also, the web page suggests all discontinuities are between 0 and 1, which is wrong as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "fractional part" function
$$
\{\,\} : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1),\quad x \mapsto \{ x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor
$$
is obviously discontinuous at every integer point.

If fact, since $\{\,\}$ is $1$-periodic, it is enough to show that it is discontinuous at $1$. For $\varepsilon>0$ small enough we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\{1+\varepsilon\}&=&1+\varepsilon-\lfloor 1+\varepsilon\rfloor=1+\varepsilon-1=\varepsilon\\
\{1-\varepsilon\}&=&1-\varepsilon-\lfloor 1-\varepsilon\rfloor=1-\varepsilon-0=1-\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to 1-}\{x\}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}(1-\varepsilon)=1\ne0=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}\varepsilon=\lim_{x\to1+}\{x\}.
$$

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then the function 
$$
u_n:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1),\quad x\mapsto \{nx\}
$$
is discontinuous at every point of the form $\frac{k}{n}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since
$$
f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u_n}{n^2+n},
$$
it follows that $f$ is discontinuous at every point of the form $\frac{k}{n}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $f$ is discontinuous at every point of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient justification.

Comment: Why does $u_n$ being discontinuous imply that $f$ is discontinuous?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Take $x=p/q \in [0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ coprime. What can you say about the continuity of $u_{nq},n \in \mathbb{N}$ at $x$?

Comment: I understand what you're getting at, but I think the fact that it's an infinite sum complicates things and requires a more formal argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Every irrational point is a point of continuity.** Let $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ be irrational. Every function
$$f_n:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R, x\mapsto\frac{\langle nx\rangle}{n^2+n}$$ is continuous at $\alpha$. The series $$\sum f_n$$ is clearly normally convergent on $\Bbb R$, whence continuity at $\alpha$.

---

**Every rational point is a point of discontinuity.** Let $p/q$ be rational (with $q$ positive.) Fix $N>>q$ such that
$$\sum_{n> N}\frac{1}{n^2+n}<\frac{1}{2(q^2+q)}$$
The function
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq N} f_n$$
experiences a discontinuity at $p/q$, specifically its value drops (at least) by $\frac{1}{q^2+q}$ when transitioning from $(p/q)^-$ to $(p/q)^+$. By definition of $N$, this drop is too big for the remainder
$$\sum_{n> N}f_n$$
to compensate for, and so $\sum f_n$ is discontinuous at $p/q$.