# Prove Series Function is Continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

How can I prove that series function is continuous with epsilon-delta definition.

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ {\displaystyle \lfloor nx\rfloor } }{n^{2}}$

a) Prove that it is discontinuous in rationals numbers.

Comment: Do you mean continuous on the irrationals?

Comment: This function is not even well-defined. For example, $f(2)= \sum_n \frac{2}{n}= \infty$

Comment: Yes, It is right.

Comment: $f$ is not defined at the integers. So $f$ is not defined on rationals too. Can you see why?

Comment: ...and do you mean fractional part (instead of floor)? Once you confirm this then... Duplicate: [Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{[nx]}{n^2} $ is discontinuous at $x \in \mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652576/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-fracnxn2-is-discontinuous-at-x-in-m)

Comment: Yes. I define the fractional part. I will check it.